# Attach generate pdf into mail in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, pdf

I've some problem with email attach generate pdf, hope you can give me some advice, please kindly help.

**Here is the Controller:**

```
public function kirim(Request $request){
    $keluhan = keluhan::findOrFail($request->id);

    $tindak = DB::table('tindakans')
    ->join('keluhans','keluhans.id','=','tindakans.id_keluhan')
    ->select(DB::raw('tindakans.id, id_keluhan, perbaikan_sementara, revisi_dokumen, target_verifikasi, ttd_tanggung1,
    ttd_tanggung2'))->get();

    $analisa = DB::table('analisas')
    ->join('tindakans','tindakans.id','=','analisas.id_tindakan')
    ->join('keluhans','keluhans.id','=','tindakans.id_keluhan')
    ->select(DB::raw('id_tindakan, analisa, tindakan, pic, tanggal_pelaksanaan'))->get();

    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('laporan.ptkp',compact('keluhan','tindak','analisa','halaman'));
    //return $pdf->stream();

    $data = array(
        'email_address'=>$request->email_address,
        'cc'=>$request->cc,
        'subject'=>$request->subject,
        'keterangantambahan'=>$request->keterangantambahan
    );

    Mail::send('laporan.kirim', $data, function($message) use($data) {
        $message->from('christian7andrew@gmail.com', 'PuraBox');
        $message->to($data['email_address']);
        if($data['cc'] != null){
            $message->cc($data['cc']);
        }
        $message->subject($data['subject']);
        $message->Attach($pdf);
    });

    return redirect('/');
}
```

How can I attach `$pdf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using:

```
$message->Attach($pdf);
```

> To add attachments to an e-mail, use the attach method on the $message object passed to your Closure. The attach method accepts the full path to the file as its first argument:
>
> [Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#attachments)

You should use the `attach` method (without the capitalize letter), and in the parameter, you need to pass the path where the pdf is, not the generated pdf. like the docs says.

```
$message->attach($pathToFile);
```

In the end, will be something like that:

```
Mail::send('laporan.kirim', $data, function($message) use($data) {
    $message->from('christian7andrew@gmail.com', 'PuraBox');
    $message->to($data['email_address']);
    if($data['cc'] != null){
        $message->cc($data['cc']);
    }
    $message->subject($data['subject']);

    //Full path with the pdf name
    $message->attach('foo/bar/mypdfname.pdf');
});
```

Comment: After generate i do this $pdf->save(base_path().'/public/document/report/laporan.pdf'); 
Then how to attach the path since i used base_path()

Answer (score 10):

### For future Googlers:

**Since Laravel 5.1** you can use `attachData()` method to directly attach generated file without the need for saving it.

***Source***:
[Manual - section **Raw Data Attachments**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#attachments)

> The attachData method accepts the raw data bytes as its first argument, the name of the file as its second argument, and an array of options as its third argument:

```
 /**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */

public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.orders.shipped')
                ->attachData($this->pdf, 'name.pdf', [
                    'mime' => 'application/pdf',
                ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which library you are using for PDF generation, but I guess there should be an API something like this,

```
$pdf = \PDF::loadView('laporan.ptkp',compact('keluhan','tindak','analisa','halaman'));

$path = storage_path('app/public/pdf/')."example.pdf";

$pdf->save($path);

return $path;
```

And then you can use the path to attach to email.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

it's very simple just add your blade in the loadView() method and pass it's pdf instance into callback

```
    public function index()
    {
        $data["email"] = "contact@cdlcell.com";
        $data["title"] = "cdlcell";
        $data["body"] = "Demo";
  
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('emails.myTestMail', $data);
  
        Mail::send('emails.myTestMail', $data, function($message)use($data, $pdf) {
            $message->to($data["email"], $data["email"])
                    ->subject($data["title"])
                    ->attachData($pdf->output(), "text.pdf");
        });
  
        dd('Mail sent successfully');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do something as

```
Mail::send('laporan.kirim', $data, function($message) use($data) {
    $message->from('christian7andrew@gmail.com', 'PuraBox');
    $message->to($data['email_address']);
    if($data['cc'] != null){
        $message->cc($data['cc']);
    }
    $message->subject($data['subject']);
    $message->Attach($pdf->output(),"name.pdf");
});

return redirect('/');
```

}

this may help you out